# A confusion about the order in the set of rational functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, rational-functions, ordered-fields, real-algebraic-geometry

In the book of *Real Algebraic Geometry* by Bocknak-Coste-Roy, at page $7$, it is given that

> There is exactly one ordering $\mathbb{R} (X)$ such that $X$ is
>   positive and smaller than any positive real number.If  $$P(X) = a_n
> > X^n + a_{n-1} X^{n-1} + ... + a_k X^k \quad with \quad a_k \not = 0,$$
>   then $P(X) > 0 $ for this ordering iff $a_k > 0$, and ...

So first of all, how can $<$ form a ordering, I mean is it not reflexive since for any $a_k$, $a_k \not > a_k$.

Plus, every source that I have looked says that the ordering is according to the leading coefficient, and not according to the constant term.

Secondly, what does the author mean by "X is positive and smaller than any positive real number" ,and how can we show that this ordering is unique since the author says "one ordering" ?

Edit: As is it point out in the comments, apparently $<$ should not be reflexive, but why ? isn't it in the definition of a total ordering ? if $< $ is not a total order, then what is it ?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean
$$P(X)=a_nX^n+\cdots+a_kX^k?$$
I don't get your point about reflexivity. We should always have $f\not>f$.

If you order according to the leading coefficient, you get a different
ordering, one where $X>a$ for all real $a$.

In this ordering $0<X<a$ for all real positive $a$.
(When the authors say
"$X$ is positive and smaller than any positive real number"
they mean $X$ is positive and smaller than any positive real number, i.e., this). For example then, if $f=X^2-X$, then
$$f=-X(1-X)<0$$
as $-X<0$ and $1-X>1-0.1>0$ etc. One can extend this argument to show
that a polynomial with positive last coefficient is positive in this ordering.

Comment: But shouldn't the total ordering be reflexive ? I mean it is in its definition.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Why do you think the total ordering should be reflexive? What definition of total ordering are you using? Are you perhaps mixing up $<$ with $\leq$? Certainly any order relation denoted by $\leq$ can be expected to be reflexive (or else it was a poorly chosen symbol). But the symbol $<$ usually means something like $f < g$ if and only if $f \geq g$ and $f \neq g$; we don't usually (like, ever) use $<$ for reflexive things.

Comment: @ZachTeitler the definition that I'm using; The relation $\leq $ is a partial ordering if it is reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric. [...] $\qquad$
3. The relation $\leq$ is a total ordering if it is a partial ordering, and if for every $a,b \in A$, at least one of a $\leq$ b or b $\geq$ a holds. If $\leq$ is a total ordering, the pair (A, 4) is a totally ordered set.

Comment: @ZachTeitler If $<$ is not a total ordering, then what is it ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas Okay, $<$ is defined by $f < g$ if and only if $f \leq g$ and $f \neq g$. Let's make up a name for it. How about "strict total order", since it is like a total order, except strictly less than (instead of less than or equal). As an exercise you can prove that $<$ is irreflexive, transitive, and asymmetric; for every $f,g$, exactly one of $f<g$, $f=g$, or $f>g$ holds. Or alternatively: You have been given a VERY clear definition of $<$. Now define $\leq$ by $f \leq g$ if and only if $f<g$ or $f=g$; check, from the definitions of $<$ and $\leq$, that $\leq$ is a total ordering.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Ok, thanks a lot.